# Usage of Profile Center with Salescloud (MC Connector)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sales-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

This might be a simple question, but I'd like to understand what are the implications of integrating SalesCloud with MC in terms of the Profile Center.

For example, if a contact updates his/her information via the Profile Center, would that information be pushed to SC and update the contact details?

As far as I understand this should happen, or at least be achievable by some means.

Hopefully someone can enlighten me, and thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty much able to find the information, so for anyone interested:

http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v2_non_enterprise_2_0/attributes_for_salesforce_leads_and_contacts_procedures/

Basically "you can set up your attributes by mapping them to fields in your Salesforce account. These attributes are used for personalization in your emails. When an attribute personalization string is included in an email that you send to your Salesforce Leads, Contacts, and Account fields, the personalization string will be replaced with the corresponding data from the Lead or Contact's record in Salesforce."

There you go!